# P3P Compact Privacy Policy

Tags: cookies, p3p

I'm trying to get our P3P implementation working. We have generated the necessary policies. We have the meta tag with the compact policy CP="some text here...". We turned off cookies on our site, launched the app, and we got an error that states cookies have been blocked. We were able to view the summary so its hitting the policy we set up. This makes sense since we turned off cookies but setting up the policies and the like, is that not supposed to just allow the cookies to go through? Then again, maybe I'm not sure what's the intended outcome.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

David W.

Comment: Have you tried using the P3P validator?
http://www.w3.org/P3P/validator.html
what exactly do you want to do... if you are still interested (I realize your post is quite old)